# Seaborn graph representation format

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIdyD.png)
[My result output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCMoa.png)

What's the problem?
The bar lines disappeared 
Thank you for answering

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCMoa.png):

Answer (score 0):

Test it but please send part of your code.

```
ax = sns.barplot(x='Date', y='y values', data=your_df)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(), your_df.Rating)
```